# Google Analytics for Android "setSampleRate" and "ga_sampleFrequency" both not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

I received an email regarding excessive hit for Google Analytics, following the instruction in the email, I added both "ga_sampleFrequency" in the tracker XML as well as programmatically setting "setSampleRate" to 1%. However, after the app is published over a month now, the hit count on Google Analytics console does not seem to have changed at all!

```
<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">1.0</string>
```

and

```
setSampleRate(1.0);
```

Neither of the above seem to be actually working.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks!